# Play Framework how to reference a file in conf folder as Java InputStream from local run and web app

Tags: java, playframework

I have an application where I need to grab a file in my Play Framework app.  I need to reference it to be used in a Java `InputStream` object.  I need to be able to reference when running the app locally for debugging as well as in the web app itself.

Here is what I am using:

```
/** Credentials File Name **/
private static String credentialsFileName = "conf/client_secret.json";

// Load client secrets...
InputStream in = GoogleDrive.class.getResourceAsStream(credentialsFileName);
GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
```

However, when I run both locally or in the web app, it does not find the file.  It causes a NullPointerException.

Where should this file be placed and how should it be referenced correctly?

### EDIT:

Here is the updated class:

```
    import javax.inject.Inject;
    import play.Environment;
...
    public class GoogleDrive {

        @Inject
        public static Environment environment;

        /** Credentials File Name **/
        private static String credentialsFileName = "client_secret.json";
    ...

    /**
         * Creates an authorized Credential object.
         * 
         * @return an authorized Credential object.
         * @throws IOException
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
            Credential credential = null;
            try {
                // Load client secrets...
                final InputStream in = environment.resourceAsStream(credentialsFileName);
                //InputStream in = GoogleDrive.class.getResourceAsStream(credentialsFileName);
                GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
    ...
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.toString());
                System.out.println("Could not find file " + credentialsFileName);
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return credential;
        }
    ...

    }
```

Comment: Maybe you can find some useful hints here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36073152/2928853

Comment: As mentioned : Injecting static fields does not work.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you're using the wrong classloader. You need to :

@Inject play.Environment, and use the resourceAsStream() method. In your case :

```
@Inject
private Environment environment;

final InputStream is = environment.resourceAsStream(credentialsFileName);
```

Comment: I have added those lines of code to my class.  However, I still get a `NullPointerException`.  I have updated my post with the code.

Comment: NPE on what ? It either means that Environment isn't injected properly, or that the file referenced can't be found. Please not that in order to use resourceAsStream(), the target file must be in the classpath.

That could also mean that the correct path is client_secret.json, since conf is on the classpath.

Comment: I receive the error on the `final InputStream in = environment.resourceAsStream(credentialsFileName);` line of code.  It errors out there and does not continue.  The file resides in the `conf` folder of my app.  How do I check to see if the Environment is the issue or the file path?

Comment: here is the output when running in Eclipse (locally): `java.lang.NullPointerException
 at google.GoogleDrive.authorize(GoogleDrive.java:93)
 at google.GoogleDrive.getDriveService(GoogleDrive.java:117)
 at google.GoogleDrive.uploadFile(GoogleDrive.java:134)
 at google.GoogleDrive.main(GoogleDrive.java:123)
ERROR: JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment, jvm->GetEnv() return code = -2
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_NO_JNI_ENV(183):  [util.c:840]`

Comment: That's most likely http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6476706. It's most likely unrelated to your issue.

Comment: I just looked at the code : You're using 

@Inject
public static Environment environment;

Injecting static fields does not work. Remove all the static members, and make the class a Singleton.